# State Machine, naming the next and previous states

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

I'm using the state_machine gem in my Rails 3.2.9 application and am trying to get the name of the next state.

I can list all states with:

```
 Order.state_machine.states.map &:name
```

But I can't see in the docs whether it's possible to get the name of the next state.

I have something like this in my model:

```
  state_machine :initial => 'stage_1', :use_transactions => false do
    event :next do
      transition :from => 'stage_1', :to => 'stage_2'
      transition :from => 'stage_2', :to => 'stage_3', :if => :is_valid?
      transition :from => 'stage_2', :to => 'stage_4'
```

If I'm on state_2, I'd like to display stage_3.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the helper methods like

```
Order.state_events
Order.state_transitions

Order.state_paths.from_name
Order.state_paths.to_name
```

Check the documentation on [instance methods](http://rdoc.info/github/pluginaweek/state_machine/master/frames)